# Prove or disprove that $f(x) + \langle x^3 -1 \rangle$ is a unit in the quotient ring $F[x]/ \langle x^3 -1 \rangle$, for $f(x) = x^2-1$ and $3x^5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Given $F$ that is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, I want prove or disprove whether $f(x) + \langle x^3 -1 \rangle$ is a unit in the quotient ring $F[x]/ \langle x^3 -1 \rangle$, given (1) $f(x) = x^2 -1$ and (2) $f(x) = 3x^5$.

I understand that $F[x]/\langle x^3 - 1\rangle$ is not a field since $x^3 -1$ is reducible in any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. So for both cases they might not have an inverse. I tried to work from definition by prove or disprove that there exists $g(x)$ such that $f(x)g(x) + \langle x^3 - 1\rangle = 1 + \langle x^3 - 1\rangle$, which is equivalent to $f(x)g(x) -1 = h(x)(x^3-1)$ for some $h(x)$. I got stuck here as I cannot prove or disprove the existence of $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ for both cases of $f(x)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\,(f)=(1)\,$ in $\,F[x]/(x^3\!-\!1)\iff (f)+(x^3\!-\!1) = (1)$ in $\,F[x]\,$ $\iff \gcd(f,x^3\!-\!1) = 1\,$ in $F[x],\,$ by Bezout, since $F[x]$ is a PID, being Euclidean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $F[x]/ \langle x^3 -1 \rangle$ consists of elements of the form
$$\{a+bx+cx^2:a,b,c\in F, x^3=1\}$$

To find inverse of $3x^5+\langle x^3-1\rangle$, note that
$$3x^5-3x^2=3x^2(x^3-1)\in\langle x^3-1\rangle$$, i.e. $3x^5+\langle x^3-1\rangle=3x^2+\langle x^3-1\rangle$ and its inverse is $\frac{x}{3}+\langle x^3-1\rangle$.

To find an inverse for $x^2-1+\langle x^3-1\rangle$, suppose the inverse is of the form
$a+bx+cx^2+\langle x^3-1\rangle$, and we want to have
$$(x^2-1+\langle x^3-1\rangle)(a+bx+cx^2+\langle x^3-1\rangle)=1+\langle x^3-1\rangle $$
or
$$(x^2-1)(a+bx+cx^2)+\langle x^3-1\rangle=1+\langle x^3-1\rangle$$
But the product $(x^2-1)(a+bx+cx^2)$ is
$$ax^2+bx^3+cx^4-a-bx-cx^2=ax^2+b+cx-a-bx-cx^2$$
because $x^3=1$ and $x^4=x(x^3)=x$ (Not that by $x^4=x$, we mean in the quotient ring, $x^4-x\in\langle x^3-1\rangle $, therefore $x^4+\langle x^3-1\rangle=x+\langle x^3-1\rangle$.)

Thus we need to have $$(b-a)+(c-b)x+(a-c)x^2=1$$
i.e. $b-a=1 $, $c=b$ and $a=c$ which has no solution, therefore $x^2-1+\langle x^3-1\rangle$ is not invertible.

Comment: Actually case (2) is $f(x) = 3x^5$ not $3x^3$. But in any case I tried to solve it with the same method provided and I got $3x^5 = 3x^2$ and so the inverse of it to be $\frac{1}{3}x$ using the method. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: well $3x^5=3x^2\cdot x^3=3x^2$ and you can use the same method as I did for $x^2-1$